# What features are you most looking forward to in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: 2010

I am personally looking forward to seeing what people can create with the Client Object Model.

One answer per post please

Comment: Converted to wiki. Please see http://www.sharepointoverflow.com/questions/432/what-is-community-wiki for why

Answer (score 7):

Compliant HTML. Hoping for no more tables used for layouts!

Comment: yeah, I would definately agree with this!

Answer (score 4):

Hopefully they've fixed everything listed on the @SPDevWiki SP2010 ["have they fixed"](http://www.sharepointdevwiki.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=11403336) page as well as nice new features.

So far from what's public the Developer Dashboard is my favourite! OH and the F5 debugging experience!

Answer (score 4):

Business Connectivity Services, and in 2010 it will be available in Sharepoint Foundation so it will be for free.

This [blog post](http://sharepointsolutions.com/sharepoint-help/blog/index.php/2009/10/whats-new-in-business-connectivity-services-bcs/) sums it up pretty good.

Answer (score 2):

The new Ribbon Control.

Answer (score 2):

An XSLT List View Web Part as [explained here](http://stsadm.blogspot.com/2008/12/custom-list-views-and-wss-40s-xslt.html). Haven't spent many difficult hours adding custom behaviour to the existing CAML-based LVWP, I'm very happy to see it bite the dust.

Answer (score 2):

Claims-based authentication...say no more...

Answer (score 2):

**Access Services** - Will this allow SP to create more flexible DB apps? 
**Multilingual features** - Looking for a *MUCH* better story than MOSS2007

Answer (score 2):

Better tools for developing in Visual Studio! Worst nightmare is it will just be another VSeWSS v.1.something

Answer (score 1):

Workflow enhancements in SharePoint designer

Answer (score 1):

Browser independence - bringing up Firefox and Safari to the same level as IE.

Answer (score 0):

Variations improved and Valid HTML!

Answer (score 0):

SandBox Solutions

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight Webparts and AJAX funvtionalities all over . .

Answer (score -1):

There are plenty of features we can say I am very interested in [SharePoint 2010](http://praveenbattula.blogspot.com/search/label/SharePoint%202010).

1. [Client Object Model](http://praveenbattula.blogspot.com/search/label/Client%20Object%20Model)
2. [Visual Upgrade](http://praveenbattula.blogspot.com/2010/02/sharepoint-2010-html-markup-changes-in.html)
3. Client Tools and deploy and integrate options in Visual Studio.
4. Improvements in SharePoint designer 2010.
5. WCF services integration and .NET 3.0 LINQ queries.
6. Site workflows, Workflows enhancement and Visio integration
   support.
7. Single master page for both application and site.
8. SQL Server PowerPivot for SharePoint
9. Chart web part.
10. Social Bookmarking options.
11. SharePoint 2010 FAST search and wild card search options.
12. Developer dashboard - Should help to devs as we can investigate
    what is taking which amount of time.
13. Sandbox solutions.
14. Web analytics web part

And last non other than [UI rendering](http://praveenbattula.blogspot.com/2010/02/sharepoint-2010-html-markup-changes-in.html). Almost all rendering is using DIVS instead of TABLES and the nice styles.

Comment: @Rare Solutions: The links in every one of your posts goes back to your blog. SharePoint Overflow isn't a vehicle for you solely to promote your blog. Please also contribute meaningful answers. Thank you!