# What are the advantages of SharePoint 2010 over SharePoint 2007?

Tags: 2007

My current employer is thinking on migrating from MOSS 2007 to SharePoint 2010. What would be the extra features that will be available for them? I already know about the huge improvement of the UI

Comment: Are you asking for out of the box features, or development features? There are huge improvements in both areas.

Comment: Well, like overall. What are the functionality that you cannot do in MOSS 2007 or that in 2010 is just out of the box or way easier?

Comment: I think this is better for a google search. did you try "sharepoint 2007 vs 2010"? Lot's of good results there with multiple pages.

Comment: Try the following Matrix: http://www.rharbridge.com/?page_id=103 or this http://www.milesconsultingcorp.com/SharePoint-2007-versus-2010-comparison.aspx

Comment: I would suggest to start from evaluation guide: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=110318ec-0238-4811-8fc7-ec4399d3c100&displaylang=en

Answer (score 1):

So from an internal perspective, it provides a ton of improvements. My top 3:

- It enables the creation and management of a firmwide taxonomy from a single hub
- Its integration with FAST allows for extremely powerful search across a number of systems with relative ease
- Its support to table relations allows for CRUD databases to be built on the server, avoiding the perils of Access and empowering business users

Answer (score 1):

you will find N no of new feature here.

[What features are you most looking forward to in SharePoint 2010?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-features-are-you-most-looking-forward-to-in-sharepoint-2010)

Thanks,
Ashish

Blog - [CrazzyCoding](http://crazzycoding.blogspot.com/)